# A Better way to check network statement?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

I use JavaScript to develop Win 8 Metro app, which can be regarded as a web app. 
Now I should check network statement to make app able to get data from service.

I have two choices:

1. One is run a loop function to check network every X seconds (X can change by time).
2. The second is doing a checking before any network request operation (such as sign in, show detail info and sign out).

I will greatly appreciated if you can tell me which way is better ? 
Or you have another solution.

Comment: What would be the point of checking before every network request operation? Attempting to do the operation itself would tell you whether or not the network is town.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207293.aspx) class provides a NetworkStatusChanged event that is fired whenever the connection state changes.

MSDN Quickstart on Managing connection state changes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700376.aspx